# Conflicting JavaScript for gyroscope move and touchmove on iOS, how do I pause one part when the second is in use?

Tags: javascript, ios, gyroscope, touchmove

I'm punching above my weight a bit with some JavaScript code on an iOS web app.

What I'm doing is moving a layer above another layer using:

1. Gyro and accelerometer data and
2. Touch input.

This means I've got two bits of javascript both trying to move the same thing. This doesn't work so well, [as you can see from the current version](http://stefanchristou.com/nyp/index-2.4.4.html) when viewed on an iOS device (hint: the transparency is turned on with the button on the right, and no, it can't be moved with a mouse right now and wont move unless you are using an iOS device with a Gyro).

So I've done the hard bits but I'm stuck on what I expect is a gotcha based on my newb(ish) level of proficiency with JavaScript.

How can I stop the gyro-move code when the touch-move code is active? Also I guess I'll need to update the x+y values so the transparency does not jump position once the touch-move ends.

I've tried adding an if, else statement to the top of the code but this seems to break the whole lot.

BTW thanks to everyone on StackOverflow, previous Q and As have been tons of help in getting me this far.

Help will be most appreciated.

Stefan

Here's my code so far, it's living in the body element...

```
var x = 0, y = 0,
    vx = 0, vy = 0,
    ax = 0, ay = 0;

var transp = document.getElementById("transp");

if (window.DeviceMotionEvent != undefined) {
    window.ondevicemotion = function(e) {
        ax = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 5;
        ay = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * 5 + 19;
        document.getElementById("accelerationX").innerHTML = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        document.getElementById("accelerationY").innerHTML = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        document.getElementById("accelerationZ").innerHTML = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;

        if ( e.rotationRate ) {
            document.getElementById("rotationAlpha").innerHTML = e.rotationRate.alpha;
            document.getElementById("rotationBeta").innerHTML = e.rotationRate.beta;
            document.getElementById("rotationGamma").innerHTML = e.rotationRate.gamma;
        }       
    }

    setInterval( function() {
        var landscapeOrientation = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight > 1;
        if ( landscapeOrientation) {
            vx = vx + ay;
            vy = vy + ax;
        } else {
            vy = vy - ay;
            vx = vx + ax;
        }
        vx = vx * 0.98;
        vy = vy * 0.98;
        y = parseInt(y + vy / 70);
        x = parseInt(x + vx / 70);

        boundingBoxCheck();

        transp.style.top = y + "px";
        transp.style.left = x + "px";

    }, 25);
} 


function boundingBoxCheck(){
    if (x<-310) { x = -310; vx = -vx; }
    if (y<-300) { y = -300; vy = -vy; }
    if (x>document.documentElement.clientWidth) { x = document.documentElement.clientWidth; vx = -vx; }
    if (y>document.documentElement.clientHeight+400) { y = document.documentElement.clientHeight+400; vy = -vy; }

}

    $.fn.moveable = function() {  
      var offset = null;  
      var start = function(e) {  
        var orig = e.originalEvent;  
        var pos = $(this).position();  
        offset = {  
          x: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - pos.left,  
          y: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - pos.top  
        };  
      };  
      var moveMe = function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();  
        var orig = e.originalEvent;  
        $(this).css({  
          top: orig.changedTouches[0].pageY - offset.y,  
          left: orig.changedTouches[0].pageX - offset.x  
        });  
      };  
      this.bind("touchstart", start);  
      this.bind("touchmove", moveMe);  
    };  

    $(".moveable").moveable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be is to have an isTouching variable that gets set to true on touchstart and set back to false on touchEnd. Then using a conditional the gyro code will only run if the isTouching variable is false. Hope that helps.